# Width of textarea and input is different when wrapping in flexbox column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to setup a multi column contact form by wrapping the texarea into a "second column" using a wrapped flexbox. I expected the textarea to be the same width as the text input. Actually, the text input (first column) is wider than the textarea (second column). In the sample I created on codepen, the difference is e.g. 12px.

In the below example, the textarea is wider than the fieldset. In this example the texarea (and the submit button) is 10px wider than the text inputs, respective the fieldset. Why is one element wider than another when it's wrapped within a flexbox?

In the code a single element should not be higher than the `max-height` of the entire flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 116px;
}

input[type=text] {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 84px;
  min-width: 0;
  resize: vertical;
}


textarea, input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="/doit" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
    </fieldset>
    <textarea>I am wider than the fieldset.</textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I tried it in Safari (Mojave) and Chrome 85.

Could anyone tell me what causes this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try using `flex-grow:1` on `input` and `textarea` https://medium.com/developedbyjohn/equal-width-flex-items-a5ba1bfacb77

Comment: Do you want them to be next to each other? because it is so in your codepen link

Comment: @Awais As far as I know, if I don't want to achieve different flow-grow behavior, I don't have to provide any flex-grow. By the way, yes I already tried it. Thx! :)

Comment: @MarcelKoch I edited my answer. Please check. Also, next time make sure you ping me (just like I have done in this comment) to inform me that you have edited your question. I did not notice that you have edited it !! And you can also find me on Discord: Omid.N#9086

Comment: Marcel, do *not* change your question after it received an answer. It invalidates the work other users have invested in answering it. Ask a follow-up question instead. @Omid.N, you are not required or expected to change your answer because the question has changed. In the future, roll back the question instead.

Comment: I edited the question into a shape that is acceptable on Stack Overflow. As said before, please don't make changes after you got an answer, don't reference a previous version that isn't visible due to your edits and don't address specific users. As mentioned above, ask a new follow-up question and reference a previous one in the future to avoid all of this. Thanks!

Comment: @ModusTollens Sorry to bother you. I meant now harm. As I wanted to answer my question here, I was told that I should update my original question and not answer my own question. With "follow-up question" you mean a complete new question? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarcelKoch Yes, a new question is the correct way to do it. In it, you can link this one for more context. Don't worry, it takes some time to get to know the rules of Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @ModusTollens Yeah, I already noticed that asking a question is a complete other beast than just reading questions and the respective answers for almost for more than a decade. Thanks for your support. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem still exists in your code. You have set the `max-height` of your `form` to `116px` (this time). The sum of the heights of `input` elements and `textarea` will definitely grow more than `116px` and since your `flex-wrap` is `wrap` it will turn to a row. So you should not expect them to be of equal width.

If you want your text inputs to be of equal size and be next to each other you must use `flex-direction: row`. Your code can be something like:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
}

input[type=text] {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

fieldset {
  flex:1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.textarea {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 84px;
  min-width: 0;
  resize: vertical;
}
.submit{
  align-self:center;
}

textarea, input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<form action="/doit" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
        <input type="text" value="Text">
    </fieldset>
    <div >
      <textarea class="textarea">I am wider than the fieldset.</textarea>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that I have wrapped your `textarea` and button in a `<div>` to be child of `form` element and gave it a `flex:1`. Then made that `<div>` a vertical flexbox itself.

Comment: Thanks again, Omid, for your try to help me out there. I know that I could solve this particular issue like you did. But a) I want to spare the the additional `div` b) I don't get why the widths don't end with same value. If you try it using two `div`s and wrap 'em you get the exact same width. Is there any explanation why this behavior occurs using a `textarea` combined with text inputs but it does not occur using `divs`? I know it's a rather theoretical discussion here but I can't explain to myself.

Comment: @MarcelKoch I have already answered why that happens! Your flexbox's max-height is set to 116px and the elements in it can't fit in that height and so they have to be in two columns but there is no guarantee that their width will be of equal size. And note that your `<input>`s' width is set to 100% that is somehow ambiguous. Because it means the full width of your element's parent(the flexbox) but it can't happen because some of the width is occupied by `<textarea>`. I will give you a useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox